# How to completely wipe out variable from JavaScript interpreter?

Tags: javascript

**Background**

- I would like to completely wipe out the variable from JavaScript interpreter.
- `delete` keyword does not work.

  ```
  > let foo = { };
  undefined
  > delete foo
  true
  > foo
  {}
  ```
- Setting variable to `undefined` does not work.

  ```
  > let foo = { };
  undefined    
  > foo = undefined
  undefined
  > foo
  undefined
  > let foo = { };
  SyntaxError: Identifier 'foo' has already been declared
  ```

**Question**

1. Is it possible to completely wipe out variable from JavaScript interpreter?
2. If yes, how to do that?

Comment: Just assign it to `null`. `delete` is for deleting properties from object.

Comment: Nope it does not work, if I assign to null `> foo = null` and I want to redeclare variable `> let foo = { };`, I receive following error: `SyntaxError: Identifier 'foo' has already been declared`, so it is not completely wiped out.

Comment: @Fuross: Assigning `null` to a variable doesn't remove the variable, it just puts the value `null` in it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to completely wipe out variable from JavaScript interpreter?

Yes and no, it depends on the variable and how it was created. You cannot remove a global `var` or `let` variable (or global `const`). For the "yes" cases, see below.

> If yes, how to do that?

It depends on where the variable is defined:

1) If it's a global variable, don't declare it with `let` or `var`; instead, assign to a property of the global object (`this` at global scope; also accessible via the global `window` on browsers or `global` on NodeJS). When you want to remove it, use `delete`.

```js
window.foo = "bar";
console.log("foo" in window); // true
console.log(foo);             // "bar"
delete window.foo;
console.log("foo" in window); // false
console.log(foo);             // ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

I should note that in loose mode, you can also do that by relying on [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)* by just assigning to an undeclared identifier:

```js
foo = "bar";
console.log("foo" in window); // true
console.log(foo);             // "bar"
delete foo;
console.log("foo" in window); // false
console.log(foo);             // ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

But...use strict mode, for exactly this reason, so typos don't make it very far. :-)

2) If it's in a function, ensure that the function returns without creating any closures. All of its local variables are then completely removed.

Comment: Funny how two users with over half a mil rep each post totally different answers

Comment: @j08691: Yup. But he deleted his. :-)